# EasyMock.anyObject() doesn't match my input

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, easymock

Not sure why, but i'm having issues with EasyMock.anyObject() not matching anything, it seems to match null, but nothing else. I have to cast to my Object too, so (MyObject)EasyMock.anyObject() in other words. My code for the AchievementsRepository looks like this.

```
when(achievementsRepository.awardBadgeAchievement((EasyMock.anyObject(AchievementsEntity.class)))).thenReturn(simpleAchievementEntity(simpleBadgeEntity(badgeId), kidzId));
```

and the code in the AchievementsRepository looks like this

```
AchievementsEntity awardBadgeAchievement = achievementsRepository.awardBadgeAchievement(achievement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It avoids any type/casting issue.

```
anyObject(AchievementsEntity.class)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.